# Displaying an alert in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm learning swift and I'm building a UI for an app, I wanted to know what was wrong with my code because it keeps saying I have errors.

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

// check for empty fields
if((userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty)
{

    //Display alert message
    displayMyAlertMessage("Alert fields are required");
    return;
}

//check if passwords match
if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword) 
// error expected expression in list of expression
{

    //Display alert message
    displayMyAlertMessage("Alert fields are required");
    return;
}
```

> expected  '(" after if condition

```
func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: String)
{
    var myAlert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Alert", 
        message: userMessage, 
        PrefferedStyle:UIAlertController.Alert);
}
```

> error Type"UIAlertController'has no member 'Alert'

Just need help figuring out the errors for the code

Comment: Why does the line "error expected expression in list of expression" exist? If it's a comment, it should start with the double slash characters.
For the other error, you misspelled "preferred". Check the spelling of the method declaration to ensure you are calling it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This code line of yours:

```
var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:
        userMessage, PrefferedStyle:UIAlertController.Alert);
```

should be:

```
var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert);
```

Alert is a case of the enum UIAlertControllerStyle, so it should be UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert instead of UIAlertController.Alert. Additionally, because the compiler know what type of enum the parameter "preferredStyle" expect, so you can use .Alert instead.

There are more '(' than ')' in your first if condition:

```
if((userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty ||
        userRepeatPassword.isEmpty) {
```

thus causing the first error. You should change it to:

```
if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty ||
            userRepeatPassword.isEmpty) {
```

And to follow Swift coding convention, you should finally change it to:

```
if userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty ||
                userRepeatPassword.isEmpty {
```

Comment: This is Swift. Why use the parentheses at all in the `if` statement?

Comment: It's just a matter of taste. I just gave him the idea of where the error comes from. I didn't try to change his coding style.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I just tried to give him the idea of where the error comes from.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text

// check for empty fields
if userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty ||
    userRepeatPassword.isEmpty {

    //Display alert message

    displayMyAlertMessage("Alert fields are required")

    return;

}

//check if passwords match
if userPassword != userRepeatPassword 

  //error expected expression in list of expression
{

  //Display alert message
    displayMyAlertMessage("Alert fields are required")
    return

}
```

You do not need () after if statements in swift. Swift might consider them as tuples. You can just do

```
if condition {


}
```

Also you do not need semicolon after each statement in swift. You can remove `;`

Comment: This doesn't actually explain what was wrong with the OP's code. And it doesn't fix the problems in the `displayMyAlertMessage` function.

Answer (score 0):

@Dat Hoang answer is correct but your alert actually won't show up until you present it. Add this line towards the end of your `displayMyAlertMessage` method

```
present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'd recommend you check out this [Swift Coding Styling Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) as well